# Connecting multiple series battery holder in parallel of 18650 batteries

Tags: parallel, series, enclosure

I'm pretty new to this, i understand how series and parallel work. Just want to ask if it's safe to connect multiple series battery holder in order for them to be parallel? If my battery are all the same, charged to all same level and same mah.

[image: 3s battery holder]

Comment: Google "battery balancing". Hint: In general, it's not OK. It might be OK in particular cases.

Comment: if you add bms on each on then parallel them would that be okay?

Comment: how should I know? Your battery management system could be *anything*.